# Opening up project from server in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to edit a project on a server. However, I can't open it as a project in visual studio 2005 because there is no sln file; I can only open up the individual aspx, vb files, references, dlls, etc.. How do I open up a folder as a complete project.

Comment: Is there a .vbproj file? Open it and save the solution. http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/slnfiles.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, try File-->Open Website.  This option does not require the existence of .sln or .vbproj files, you just point it to the appropriate directory.  Once you get it open you can re-save to generate the solution file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "Open Website" option for Visual Studio 2005. [You can see my menus from my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb6Zt.png)